# .htaccess file redirecting to parent directory

Tags: htaccess, 500-internal-error

I am creating separate WordPress installations in several subdirectories of one domain.

At first I was getting a 500 Server Internal error.. so I created the .htaccess file and uploaded it to each WordPress installation root.

.HTACCESS file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /zingery/wordpress/
RewriteRule . /zingery/wordpress/index.php [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

Now, when I go to the root directory to complete the WordPress installation, I am redirected back to the parent directory.

Here is a link with the example:

http://example.com/fusys/temp/

When you click on "zingery" and then "wordpress" it takes you back to /temp

Any idea what is going on?

If you click on "test" in the temp directory it properly displays the index.php file inside that folder (the test directory does NOT contain a WP installation). This implies to me the parent redirect issue is WordPress related.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Should be `RewriteBase /name-of-folder/` and then `RewriteRule . /name-of-folder/index.php [L]`

Comment: Can you test without that other crap in the `.htaccess`? Just core WP rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the sake of clarity, this should be your `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /zingery/wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /zingery/wordpress/index.php [L]
```

Comment: I updated it to your code and it just redirects back to the /temp directory again now. You can see what I mean with the live link I provided.

Comment: Does it make a difference that WordPress is NOT installed at this point? Only the files are residing on the server

Comment: As it turns out, my index.php file was somehow mixed with another index.php that contained a header redirect.. which explains why I was being redirected! Thanks for the help